# Qt: unable to initialize QApplication object

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5, qmake

I'm learning Qt from a youtube channel. In one of tutorials it was explained how to create empty qt projects, the tutorial intended to write this code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("hello World!");

    label->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I was getting a "no such file or directory exists" in both `#includes` so I searched the Qt include directory for those files and modifies the include statements to:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
```

Now, I get 51 errors about "unresolved external symbol" and "File not found: main.obj". If I change `char *argv[]` to `char *argv`, I get an error in the line:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

stating

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'char **'
```

I do not know what is the problem as the code in tutorial works fine (though he used Qt 2.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below works fine for me. Do not forget the `QT += widgets` entry in your qmake project file for Qt 5 if you happen to use qmake.

The widget classes were moved into their separate widgets module in Qt 5. They were living in the gui module in Qt 4, and the core and gui modules are added by default to the QT variable.

Alternatively, I am providing the raw compilation command as well.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("hello World!");

    label->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

#### Build

> g++ -Wall -fPIC -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Core -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore main.cpp

Use this in your qmake project file:

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Do not forget to rerun qmake if you use QtCreator. Unfortunately, there is a long-standing (more than four years old at the time of writing this) issue reported against QtCreator that it does not always know when to rerun qmake when needed. See the details here:

[Creator should know when to rerun qmake](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-231)

Comment: I added `QT += widgets` in .pro file but I'm still getting all the errors mentioned in original question along with "no such file or directory" error. I'm using 'Qt Creator' and 'Qt 5.1.1'.

Comment: @HarshilSharma: there is an option in there to explicitly execute qmake (rerun). You will need to do that for the changes to take effect. Also, make sure you have the widgets module properly installed.

Comment: That worked! BTW how exactly did running qmake solve this issue? And is the difference in include statements occurring because of different Qt versions?

Comment: @HarshilSharma: 1) the project file is parsed by qmake, and since you added a line to the project file, it was unknown for make. qmake had to regenerate the new Makefile. 2) Yes, the widget classes were moved into a separate widgets module in Qt 5. They were available in the gui module in Qt 4 which is included by default in the QT variable.

Comment: But in Qt Creator, whenever I edit the project file and press Ctrl+s, a pop-up appears in bottom-right corner saying 'evaluating' and 'parsing' along with progress bar. What could that be doing then?